# Excel macro cell address increase

Tags: vba, excel, macros

Can i increase the cell address by using macro?
I'm implementing excel cell color matching function.

Example:
When i change the cell "A1" to red, cell "D1" will change to red.
if change "C1" to red, "F1" will change to red too. All need to increase 3 column.

Now i just need to modify the "c.Address" by + 3 so the cell will go do D1.
I try using c.Address + 3 but it can't work.
Any help will be appreciate!

Thanks!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

For Each c In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C1").Cells

    If c.Interior.Color = 255 Then
    Sheet1.Range(c.Address + 3 ).Interior.Color = 255  <<-- Can't work

    Else
    Sheet1.Range(c.Address + 3 ).Interior.Color = white <<-- Can't work

    End If

Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to have this automatically run every time you select a different cell on the worksheet? Perhaps you meant it to be triggered whenever a value on the worksheet is changed.

Comment: To turn color off use `.Interior.Pattern = xlNone`. Changing the fill color to `vbWhite` (note: not `White`) is not the same as removing the color.

Comment: If this event macro is in the Sheet1 code sheet then you do not need `Worksheets("Sheet1")` or `Sheet`. It is a private sub that knows who it belongs to. This is one of the few occasions when it is better to use `Range` instead of `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range` or `Sheet1.Range`.

Comment: Thanks Jeeped and Dirk Reichel for your info! I had get the answer dy. Yours info is useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
Sheet1.Range(c.Address + 3 )
```

To this

```
Sheet1.Range(c.Address).offset(0,3)
```

Although I don't know why you need `Sheet1.Range(c.Address)` and not just c, is c a range? if so you can just do `c.offset(0,3)`

Comment: this is actually what i want! Simple straight forward! Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

I really hoped, that Sixthsense is going to edit his answer so I can give him the +1 but it doesn't look like that will happen :(
Still knowing what he tried to achieve, I will at least show some working code and explain it a bit. So first things first: the code:

```
Option Explicit

Dim rngHolder As Range

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
  If rngHolder Is Nothing Then Set rngHolder = Intersect(Selection, Range("A1:C1"))
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Not rngHolder Is Nothing Then
    Dim rngRunner As Variant
    For Each rngRunner In rngHolder.Cells
      rngRunner.Offset(0, 3).Interior.Color = IIf(rngRunner.Interior.Color = 255, 255, xlNone)
    Next
  End If
  Set rngHolder = Intersect(Target, Range("A1:C1"))
End Sub
```

The `rngHolder` (like the `sPrev` from Sixthsense) is important, because changing the selection, does not return the "old" selection. If you select `A1` and change the color no trigger will be activated, so we are going with the `Worksheet_SelectionChange`. Now after the change, we select `D19` and nothing will tell us that `A1` has been changed. But we also do not want to run all changes every time the selection changes. For this reason the "last" selection will be stored inside the `rngHolder`.

I skipped some parts and directly push the selected ranges which cross the cells we need to look at in the variable (or nothing if no intersect is found).

If `rngHolder` is not empty the next time we select a different cell, it will run all cells in `rngHolder` to change the background color of the desired cells 3 columns to the right. (this way also changing multiple cells at once will work) and also push the new intersect in the `rngHolder`.

To the point which I was complaining about the solution of Sixthsense:
If the first selection you do is ...lets say `X7`... then selecting `A3` afterwards will change the background color of `AA7` to the same like `X7` has. This may be not noticed due to conditional formatting and stuff like that. Wrong "highlight" however may leed to user-errors later on (you also may notice it at a point lots of cells have allready beed changed)

However, the question was just for the "Offset"-function which is already answered in a proper way ;)

Answer (score -1):

Replace your current code with the below one.

```
Dim sPrev As String
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If sPrev = "" Then sPrev = Target.Address

If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
    If Target.Column = Range("A:A").Column Then
        With Range(sPrev)
            .Offset(, 3).Interior.Color = .Interior.Color
        End With
        sPrev = Target.Address
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm confused... fow what reason the `If Target.Column = Range("A:A").Column Then`? While it is the same like `If Target.Column = 1 Then`, that is not what was looked for. Also `.Offset(, 3).Interior.Color = .Interior.Color` is not desired. Also your `sPrev` will mess up the way the macro works. It kinda looks like a copy-paste frome somewhere (just skipped out some parts which are not in need here). You also do not explain anything. Pls review your answer...

Comment: You downvoted my answer and if you don't have the knowledge of understanding my code then it is not my duty to make you understand it.

Comment: Quote: *"Replace your current code with the below one."* but your code will not do what the OP is looking for... not at all. it may also mess up his sheet. just for this part, I may push your answer to a -2

Comment: What's the purpose of using sprev? converting a range to a string to then use it in a `Range()` command, why not just use the range object ie Target? This seems extremely over engineered. I can't see a reason for it but would be very keen to learn if you can explain it @Sixthsense

Comment: @DanDonoghue pls check my answer. it should explain everything in a proper way (hopefully) ;)

Comment: Ah I see, got it now. Thanks for the explanation, I have learned something :) (I still don't like the use of a string in this case but in your code you used a range :))